# Python sort strings by count of appearances of the strings in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of strings `tags` which I wish to sort by count of appearances of the strings in the list.

I have tried:

Creating the list of unique strings,

```
uniqueTags = set(tags)
```

Then creating a second list with the counts for each of the unique string

```
countList = []
for items in uniqueTags:
    countList.append(tags.count(items))
```

but then I am not sure how to sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter(...)` instead.

```
In [18]: from collections import Counter

In [19]: m = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c']

In [20]: Counter(m).most_common()
Out[20]: [('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

`Counter.most_common()` returns a list of a tuple such that the first element is the string and the second is it's count and the list is ordered by the count.

```
In [21]: m2 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b']

In [22]: Counter(m2).most_common()
Out[22]: [('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Just to get a list of items, you could do

```
In [28]: [elem for elem, _ in Counter(m2).most_common()]
Out[28]: ['b', 'a', 'c']
```

If you're looking to sort the list you got, change your method to something like

```
In [23]: final_list = []

In [24]: for elem in set(m2):
    ...:     final_list.append((elem, m2.count(elem)))
    ...:     

In [25]: from operator import itemgetter

In [26]: sorted(final_list, key=itemgetter(1))
Out[26]: [('c', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]

In [27]: sorted(final_list, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
Out[27]: [('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('c', 1)]
```

Comment: And of course to get just a list of items: `[x for x, _ in Counter(m).most_common()]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter
get_val = itemgetter(0)

def retrieve_unique_sorted_by_count(lst)
    return [get_val(x) for x in Counter(lst).most_common()]
```